# WPF - How to display different Controls based on ComboBox's SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, user-controls

I don't know all the techical terms yet, but I'll try to explain my problem the best possible way.

My program consists of a `Main Window` where variables are defined. I want to use a `ComboBox` with four `ComboBoxItem`s. For each `ComboBoxItem`, I want a new section to open below the `ComboBox` and in this section the input will continue to get the last value I want. For info, only one `ComboBoxItem` will be active.

I've tried a `UserControl` that opens in a `StackPanel` under the `ComboBox` in `Main Window`, but I want to possibility to enter row definitions and column definitions in this section and I couldn't do that in the usercontrol window.

Can anyone guide me please to a topic I can read for this method?

Comment: Have you tried using [popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.110).aspx)? You have to scroll way down the page to see the xml code example on that page. You can put a grid containing any other user control in that.  I don't think it shows as an option in the wpf toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I got it right... You wanna display a different `Content` deppending on which `ComboBoxItem` the user selected? If that's the case, all you have to do is create a an `x` number of pages (where `x` is the amount of different options) and a `Frame` below the `ComboBox`. In those pages you can put whatever you want: from a `DataGrid` to a simple `Label`. Then all you have to do is set the frame's `Content` to one of these Pages, according to the `SelectedIndex` each time the `ComboBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired.

Here's an example:

```
public void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(MyComboBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            MyFrame.Content = new MyPage1();
            break;
        case 1:
            MyFrame.Content = new MyPage2();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sort of works, but when I for example add a label and a button in the pages, when loaded, the back and forward button shows like it was a file explorer if you know what I mean?

The way I have organized the first section of my program is with RowDefinitions and all labels, textboxes and comboboxes are in these rows. Is it possible to do that in a page aswell?

Comment: You mean put the rows and columns? Sure! Use a Grid inside the page and put the rows and colums there